# a habit or practice being more powerful than another

Tags: vocabulary

Is the following sentence grammatical?

```
Ron's patience exceeds his anger.
```

Ron is a cool-minded man. He is natural to dislike something and may show anger but when anything of such sort happens, he controls his anger because he has got more patience than anger.

My question is about the word 'exceed' here.

Comment: **He is natural to dislike something....** is NOT grammatical. Nor is **anything of such sort..**

Comment: @Ronald Sole By the way, why is this ungrammatical?

Comment: You make a fair point. I should have said, not idiomatic. Typical expressions are: **of such a nature / kind** or **of this kind / sort**. I have never come across **of such sort**. That's not to say that you can't use it if you choose.

Comment: exceeds is greater than. He, naturally, dislikes some things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I would understand this sentence as expected. It is a good way to say this.